# En widget Text de tkinter, como cambiar de color el texto sin cambiar todo

Tags: python, tkinter

me gustaria me ayudaran a como hacer para que cada vez que seleccione, apagado o encendido, de los radiobutton, se me ponga de un color como en el código.
Actualmente, me cambia todo y quisiera que cada opcion conservara su color, que la fecha y la hora se mantenga en su color, y que "Encendido" apareciera en azul, y "Apagado" en rojo.

```
import locale
from time import strftime, time
import tkinter as tk
# from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
from rich import print as rprint

class App (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        Servidor = '127.0.0.1'

        #self.tSalida = tk.Text(self.master,height=100,width=740,font=("Courier New",9))
        self.tSalida = tk.Text(self.master,width=108,height=20,wrap="word", bg="lightblue",font=("Courier New",9))
        self.tSalida.place(x=10,y=40)
        H = datetime.now().strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        self.lblEje = tk.Label(self.master,text='Ejecutado desde: ' + H,bg="lightblue")
        self.lblEje.place(x=10,y=350)
        self.lblDias = tk.Label(self.master,text='00', bd=.5, bg="lightblue", relief="solid")
        self.lblDias.place(x=270,y=350)
        self.lblDias2 = tk.Label(self.master,text='00:00:00', bg="lightblue", bd=.5, relief="solid")
        self.lblDias2.place(x=300,y=350)

        self.cuadro1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.master,width=100,height=200,text = 'Estado',background="#2F539B")
        self.Estado = tk.StringVar()
        self.Estado.set("Apagado")
        # Crear los Radiobutton y asociarlos a la misma variable
        self.radio1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.cuadro1, width=10,anchor=tk.W, text="Encendido", variable=self.Estado, value="Encendido",command=self.Cambiar_ON_OFF,background="#2F539B")
        self.radio2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.cuadro1, width=10,anchor=tk.W, text="Apagado", variable=self.Estado, value="Apagado",command=self.Cambiar_ON_OFF,background="#2F539B")
        # Posicionar los Radiobutton en la ventana
        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.cuadro1.place(x=670,y=350)

        self.cerrar = tk.Button(self.master,text='CERRAR',width=10,height=1, command=self.salir,bg='#2B3856')
        self.cerrar.place(x=580,y=390)
            
        self.MostrarHora()
        self.tSalida.insert(tk.END, self.Ahora()+f'Estado: {self.Estado.get()}\n')           

    def salir(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def MostrarHora(self):
        display_time = datetime.now().strftime("%A %d de %B de %Y %H:%M:%S")
        self.lblAhora.config(text=display_time)
        self.lblAhora.after(1000,self.MostrarHora)
        pass
                
    def Cambiar_ON_OFF(self):
        if self.Estado.get() == 'Encendido':
            self.tSalida.tag_configure("colorido", foreground="blue")
        #    self.tSalida.insert(tk.END, f'{self.Estado.get()}\n',"colorido")
        else:
            self.tSalida.tag_configure("colorido", foreground="red")
        self.tSalida.insert(tk.END,self.Ahora()+f'{self.Estado.get()}\n',"colorido")        

    def Ahora(self):
        return datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S ")
    
    def Llamar_config(self):
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    version = '0.0.1'
    raiz = tk.Tk()
    myapp = App(raiz)
    raiz.config(width=780,height=650)
    raiz.title(" 2024")
    raiz.mainloop()
```

Supongo que estará en el tk.END de cada insert, pero no localizo el código ni la opción.

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te cambia todo el texto previo porque al cambiar la configuración de una etiqueta los cambios se aplican a todo el texto insertado con ella que este presente en el cuadro de texto.

En vez de cambiar el color asociado a la etiqueta, usa diferentes etiquetas:

```
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.salida = tk.Text(parent)
        self.salida.tag_configure("Apagado", foreground="red")
        self.salida.tag_configure("Encendido", foreground="blue")
        self.salida.tag_configure("Fecha", foreground="gray")
        self.salida.pack()
        
        switch_frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        switch_frame.pack()

        self.estado = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Radiobutton(
            switch_frame,
            text="Apagado",
            variable=self.estado,
            indicatoron=False,
            value="Apagado",
            width=13,
            command=self.on_estado
            ).pack(side="left")
        
        tk.Radiobutton(
            switch_frame,
            text="Encendido",
            variable=self.estado,
            indicatoron=False,
            value="Encendido",
            width=13,
            command=self.on_estado
        ).pack(side="left")
        
        self.estado.set("Apagado")

    def on_estado(self):
        fecha = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S ")
        estado = self.estado.get()
        self.salida.insert(tk.END, fecha, "Fecha", f'{estado}\n', estado)        

     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

A `tkinter.Text.insert` le puedes pasar las parejas de texto, tag (o tags) que deses:

```
insert(tk.END, "text_a", tag_text_a, "text_b", (tag1_text_b, tag2_text_b), ...)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias,, lo voy a probar.

Comment: Despues algunas pruebas y "acomodar" a mi código... me funciona. Gracias.